# What is a through-hole equivalent to the irlml6401 P-channel MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, p-channel

Newbie here. My hobby project uses the irlml6401 P-channel MOSFET but I'm finding it impossible to solder the surface-mount package it comes in because I have trembly hands (gets worse as I try to be more precise).

Is there a through-hole equivalent I can use (max current won't exceed 3 amps)? I've searched online for hours but the number of parameters to compare is bewildering and I'm not sure which I can effectively ignore and which are important.

I'm using it as a high-side switch.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: The way you've phrased this is makes it an off-topic "shopping" question. To make this on-topic you'll need to give some more detail on how this MOFSET is used in the circuit, the nature of what it's high-side switching, amount of current you're expecting it to source, voltage levels, etc. With those details in your question, then perhaps you could re-phrase your question more along the line of "what parameters are important when looking for an equivalent", rather than "what part should I buy".

Comment: Ah, ok. i understand why it's off topic. Thanks for making me aware :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, your question as asked is a bit too broad and off-topic, however, I can try to answer it in a way that is generic and hopefully useful.

First of all, you are saying you cannot hand-solder SOT-23 MOSFET, which could be a problem because through-hole components can also be hard to solder when they have tiny closely spaced pins.  If the part is not a SOT-23, then here is a good hint of why missing information from your question makes it hard to answer it.

Given that you are asking for an alternative, I can only assume that you are also designing the PCB - again, if not, hint on why you need to provide this information.  The reason I'm bringing this up is that if you are designing the PCB, there are ways to make footprints more manual-solder-friendly by extending the pads or doing similar tricks that could make it possible to hand-solder.

Lastly, if all of the above fails and you need to identify an alternative MOSFET, there are a few key parameters that you should focus on.  Most online vendors have a filter function so as you specify parameters you see what is available.  Again, it is possible that your circuit has some design parameters that heavily depend on a MOSFET parameter that I'm not listing below, but without that information, that's the next best thing.

Key parameters to look for:

1. P-Channel (obviously)
2. Maximum Drain-to-Source voltage; your part is 12V, anything over that will work
3. Drive Voltage - this is the gate voltage needed to 'open' the MOSFET.  Your part lists that as 1.8V minimum, with 4.5V as the min Rds value, so you need something with similar numbers here.  In particular, anything with a minimum voltage much higher than 1.8V could be a problem; how higher?  without a circuit, we can only guess, so hint as to why putting your circuit in the question is useful.
4. Rds ON (Max) - your part lists 50mOhm at 4.3A @4.5V Vgs - understand this is just a single point in a curve that fully defines the MOSFET but it is useful as it shows something akin to the max performance of the part.  You need to look for similar or better numbers (better would be lower Rds or similar Rds but at lower Vgs).
5. Vgs max - maximum gate voltage; your part shows +-8V, which is relatively low so any part with a higher limit should suffice.
6. Continuous drain current - your part shows 4.3A - any part with similar or higher current should work.

As a final hint, when you use the filter function on an online vendor's web site to search for alternatives, plug in the most "constraining" parameters first; here, I would guess that would be P-Channel, 1.8V/4.5V drive voltage.  Out of the available parts, you can then sort by Rds On (max) and see what is available, keeping an eye for Vds to be over 12v and sustained drain current to be over 4A or so.

Just for fun, I spend about 30 seconds to do this on my favorite online vendor and found one acceptable part (albeit with a bit higher Rds), but of course, the point is not to make a part recommendation, rather than explain how you can do this yourself.

Comment: I would also suggest to the OP to pick a package he is comfortable soldering, and starting with that as a filter.

Comment: Not a bad policy but with such low gate drive voltage and Rds, there are slim pickings.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help me get this resolved, @Yiannis. With the info you've provided, I'm sure I'll be able to find a suitable alternative by focussing only on the important parameters you've highlighted.